# obtener url completa con php en la api de facebook con php

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-api

Buenas tardes estimados

tengo el siguiente problema, necesito obtener la url completa con php de un producto x, donde en una tienda virtual tengo un boton like de facebook utilizando su api.

la url la estoy obteniendo en php de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

                $link = $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
                $url_utf8 = htmlspecialchars($link, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

            ?>
```

y por medio de javascript con el siguiente codigo:

```js
                function showSocialButtons() {

                    var script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.async = true;
                    script.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=267603823260704';
                    //script.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_ES/all.js#xfbml=1';
                    //document.getElementById('fb-root').innerHTML = 'Me gusta';
                    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(script);


                    script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.async = true;
                    script.src = document.location.protocol + '//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
                    document.getElementById('social-buttons').appendChild( script );

                    script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.async = true;
                    script.src = document.location.protocol + '//apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
                    document.getElementById( 'social-buttons' ).appendChild( script );

                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        document.getElementById('social-buttons').removeAttribute('class');
                    }, 3000 );

                };

                showSocialButtons();
```

al hacer un echo en php me devuelve la url tal cual la necesito, pero al dar like con la api de facebook solo retorna el nombre del dominio

Comment: Quiero añadir otra pregunta , como le cambio el nombre al boton like de facebook por me gusta

Comment: En cuanto a la primera pregunta, en la documentación de la API de Facebook debe haber algo referente a la URL y lo único que estás proporcionando es ID de aplicación. De la segunda pregunta, en la URL del script tienes `en_US`, supongo que bastaría con cambiar a `es_ES` o el de tu preferencia, como `es_MX`.

Comment: esa solucion ya la habia intentado y el resultado es el mismo